# How Can a Programming Language be both Statically-Typed and Dynamically-Typed?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, static, typing

Statically-typed languages and dynamically-typed languages in principle seem like opposite concepts. However, how can a language like Objective-C for example be both of these things at once? It seems to me that Objective-C is more static than dynamic. Can somebody explain how this is possible?

Comment: How? At the expense of both paradigms.

Answer (score 31):

I believe you are confusing static *typing* and dynamic *method resolution*. Objective-C is definitely strongly, statically typed. Like C, all variables must be declared and typed (there isn't even type inference as in other modern, statically typed languages). The compiler generates code based on the type of variables and this type cannot be changed at runtime.

However, Objective-C method calls use a message passing paradigm, where the message name and target are encoded at compile time, but the address of the code to execute is looked up at runtime by the Objective-C runtime libraries.

Comment: I actually was wondering this same question because in the Apple Objective-C documentation is states that Objective-C is dynamically typed because of the dynamic method resolution. I agree that the documentation should not confuse people by saying it's dynamically typed based on this functionality.

Comment: Is it not "optionally-typed" though, considering that you could, if you wanted to, make all the Obj-C objects type _id_ and completely disregard types aside from C primitives, like _int_ if you are using them?

Comment: @orange80, `id` *is* a type. In fact, all object instances in Objective-C are—to the compiler—type `id` (a `struct objc_object*`). Static typing is not optional in C, nor in Objective-C.

Comment: I'm confused... From the docs: Cocoa Core Competencies 

"A variable is dynamically typed when the type of the object it points to is not checked at compile time. Objective-C uses the id data type to represent a variable that is an object without specifying what sort of object it is. This is referred to as dynamic typing. Dynamic typing contrasts with static typing, in which the system explicitly identifies the class to which an object belongs at compile time." 

So can obj-c be dynamically typed or not?

Answer (score 11):

Objective-C is really (conceptually) just a layer on the C language itself and, as such, can have both static and dynamic types. Static if you're using the base-C stuff, dynamic if you're using the Objective-C extensions.

But C also sort-of provides this feature. If you just think about the void * type in C, you'll see that it can point to any type, hence giving you a (very rough) dynamically-typed language.

For example:

```
int i;
float f;
double d;
void *p = &i;
p = &f;
p = &d;
```

At all those assignments to `p` above, it's made to point to a different type. If you do your code cleverly enough, you can even emulate RTTI and polymorphism in C.

I would consider a language *primarily* statically or dynamically typed, based on what it was *most* used for.

Answer (score 1):

C is a statically-typed language, but it has the flexibility to re-cast types to other types, and to use generic pointers (the void* type). The void* type means "a pointer to an unspecified type of data". Objective-C implements its dynamic types through the use of these void* types, though usually this is abstracted away by multiple levels of defines, typedefs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C has a mixture of static and dynamic typing.  The plain C objects are statically typed, but the Objective-C objects are dynamically typed.  The Objective-C runtime does not care what type an object is as long as the messages you send to your objects are recognised by the object.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about the technical ability to support both idioms, that's not a particularly interesting question. Just look at most modern languages and see how they do it. Usually, it's via some kind of catch-all dynamic type (`Object` in VB, `dynamic` in C#, `void*` in C, and so on).

At the metaphysical/ontological level, this question is much more interesting...

A theory in physics might suggest behaviour that defies intuition, leading one to ask, "How can that be?" For instance, the wave-particle duality goes beyond any commonsensical notion of how reality is or ought to be, and so it leaves us pondering the imponderable.

Programming languages, however, are not models of reality. They are inventions of the mind, designed to serve our purposes. It is thus meaningless to ponder how a programming language can be the way it is. It is that way because we wanted it to be that way; because it suits our purposes. No other reason is necessary or warranted.

So please understand that I am not being flippant or dismissive when I answer that a language can be both dynamic and static just because it can, and because this is useful. It is hopeless to try to probe any further.

Comment: This is one of the most obnoxious, unhelpful answers I have ever seen on SO.

Comment: what I understood from all this is that it is because people made it that way.. in too many words maybe.

Answer (score -1):

Statically-typed languages and dynamically-typed languages are indeed opposites - at least in the way these terms are normally used.

A statically-typed language is one that includes a type checking (and reporting) phase during compilation (or at least prior to code execution).  Objective C certainly has this, so is statically typed.

A dynamically-typed language is one lacking such a type checking phase.  Hence Objective C is not dynamically-typed by this definition - and I think this is the most standard definition.

However, Objective C is sometimes called dynamically-typed (in addition to statically typed) because it allows the programmer to specify reduced static type checking in parts of their code - particularly for objects via the special static type `id`.  Personally I think it would be less confusing to say that it is a statically-typed language with good support for dynamically-typed objects.

Note that nearly all statically-typed languages include some support for dynamic typing, since e.g., they use run-time checks to catch division by zero errors, array bounds errors, downcast errors, etc.  Such things don't justify calling a language dynamically typed, otherwise nearly all languages would have to be called dynamically typed.